# Copy existing website to new project (web app/site) visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I have a website which I need to update, but I've lost the local files.

I have started a new web application, all empty, in visual studio 2010.
How can I log in the web site and copy all the files into my new project so I can work with it?  (I have the login details like ftp address and password)

Comment: Can you see the files when you login using an ftp program like FileZilla?

Comment: I tried FileZilla, it works, I can download the files and back it up.
But how do I connect it to VS, so I have a more production/developement environment in sync?

Comment: I tried opening asp.net website (NOT web app) and I see a copy website tool.
However I don't see where I can configure the directory of the source website. example. remote website: url/httpdocs/images -> source website "The ~\directory does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VS project, place the files you copied down from FTP into your VS folders in the same structure it is on the site (for example your .csproj and web.config in the same folder which acts as a root.  Then you can view all files in Visual Studio and include the files and folders you need for your site into your VS project.